App crashing when trying to retrieve a RoomDatabase object through Hilt
Kind of a follow-up from this: Trying to connect a view model to a screen using Jetpack Compose for room database
My app crashes when I tried to access a screen that has a view model attached to it, every other screen is working fine.
Here is the error:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot find implementation for com.example.fyp.EntryDatabase. EntryDatabase_Impl does not exist
    at androidx.room.Room.getGeneratedImplementation(Room.kt:58)
    at androidx.room.RoomDatabase$Builder.build(RoomDatabase.kt:1351)
    at com.example.fyp.AppModule.provideDatabase(AppModule.kt:24)
    at com.example.fyp.AppModule_ProvideDatabaseFactory.provideDatabase(AppModule_ProvideDatabaseFactory.java:42)
    at com.example.fyp.DaggerDataBaseApplication_HiltComponents_SingletonC$SingletonCImpl$SwitchingProvider.get(DaggerDataBaseApplication_HiltComponents_SingletonC.java:581)
    at dagger.internal.DoubleCheck.get(DoubleCheck.java:47)
    at com.example.fyp.DaggerDataBaseApplication_HiltComponents_SingletonC$SingletonCImpl$SwitchingProvider.get(DaggerDataBaseApplication_HiltComponents_SingletonC.java:578)
    at dagger.internal.DoubleCheck.get(DoubleCheck.java:47)
    at com.example.fyp.DaggerDataBaseApplication_HiltComponents_SingletonC$SingletonCImpl$SwitchingProvider.get(DaggerDataBaseApplication_HiltComponents_SingletonC.java:575)
    at dagger.internal.DoubleCheck.get(DoubleCheck.java:47)
    at com.example.fyp.DaggerDataBaseApplication_HiltComponents_SingletonC$ViewModelCImpl$SwitchingProvider.get(DaggerDataBaseApplication_HiltComponents_SingletonC.java:441)
    at dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.HiltViewModelFactory$1.create(HiltViewModelFactory.java:102)
    at androidx.lifecycle.AbstractSavedStateViewModelFactory.create(AbstractSavedStateViewModelFactory.kt:90)
    at dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.HiltViewModelFactory.create(HiltViewModelFactory.java:114)
    at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.kt:184)
    at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.kt:150)
    at androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.compose.ViewModelKt.get(ViewModel.kt:215)
    at androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.compose.ViewModelKt.viewModel(ViewModel.kt:156)
    at com.example.fyp.AddEntryScreenKt.AddJournalScreen(AddEntryScreen.kt:284)
    at com.example.fyp.AppNavigationKt$AppNavigation$1$8.invoke(AppNavigation.kt:54)
    at com.example.fyp.AppNavigationKt$AppNavigation$1$8.invoke(AppNavigation.kt:53)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:139)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:35)
    at androidx.navigation.compose.NavHostKt$NavHost$14$1.invoke(NavHost.kt:308)
    at androidx.navigation.compose.NavHostKt$NavHost$14$1.invoke(NavHost.kt:306)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:109)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:35)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:248)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.saveable.SaveableStateHolderImpl.SaveableStateProvider(SaveableStateHolder.kt:84)
    at androidx.navigation.compose.NavBackStackEntryProviderKt.SaveableStateProvider(NavBackStackEntryProvider.kt:65)
    at androidx.navigation.compose.NavBackStackEntryProviderKt.access$SaveableStateProvider(NavBackStackEntryProvider.kt:1)
    at androidx.navigation.compose.NavBackStackEntryProviderKt$LocalOwnersProvider$1.invoke(NavBackStackEntryProvider.kt:52)
    at androidx.navigation.compose.NavBackStackEntryProviderKt$LocalOwnersProvider$1.invoke(NavBackStackEntryProvider.kt:51)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:109)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:35)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:228)
    at androidx.navigation.compose.NavBackStackEntryProviderKt.LocalOwnersProvider(NavBackStackEntryProvider.kt:47)
    at androidx.navigation.compose.NavHostKt$NavHost$14.invoke(NavHost.kt:306)
    at androidx.navigation.compose.NavHostKt$NavHost$14.invoke(NavHost.kt:295)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:139)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:35)
    at androidx.compose.animation.AnimatedContentKt$AnimatedContent$6$1$5.invoke(AnimatedContent.kt:755)
    at androidx.compose.animation.AnimatedContentKt$AnimatedContent$6$1$5.invoke(AnimatedContent.kt:744)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:118)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:35)
    at androidx.compose.animation.AnimatedVisibilityKt.AnimatedEnterExitImpl(AnimatedVisibility.kt:818)
    at androidx.compose.animation.AnimatedContentKt$AnimatedContent$6$1.invoke(AnimatedContent.kt:726)
    at androidx.compose.animation.AnimatedContentKt$AnimatedContent$6$1.invoke(AnimatedContent.kt:709)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:109)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:35)
    at androidx.compose.animation.AnimatedContentKt.AnimatedContent(AnimatedContent.kt:768)
    at androidx.navigation.compose.NavHostKt.NavHost(NavHost.kt:273)
    at androidx.navigation.compose.NavHostKt$NavHost$17.invoke(Unknown Source:27)
    at androidx.navigation.compose.NavHostKt$NavHost$17.invoke(Unknown Source:10)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.RecomposeScopeImpl.compose(RecomposeScopeImpl.kt:192)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.recomposeToGroupEnd(Composer.kt:2556)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.skipCurrentGroup(Composer.kt:2827)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.doCompose(Composer.kt:3314)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.recompose$runtime_release(Composer.kt:3265)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.recompose(Composition.kt:940)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer.performRecompose(Recomposer.kt:1155)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer.access$performRecompose(Recomposer.kt:127)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer$runRecomposeAndApplyChanges$2$1.invoke(Recomposer.kt:583)
    at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer$runRecomposeAndApplyChanges$2$1.invoke(Recomposer.kt:551)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiFrameClock$withFrameNanos$2$callback$1.doFrame(AndroidUiFrameClock.android.kt:41)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiDispatcher.performFrameDispatch(AndroidUiDispatcher.android.kt:109)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiDispatcher.access$performFrameDispatch(AndroidUiDispatcher.android.kt:41)
    at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidUiDispatcher$dispatchCallback$1.doFrame(AndroidUiDispatcher.android.kt:69)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1229)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1239)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:899)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:827)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:1214)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7872)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
    Suppressed: kotlinx.coroutines.internal.DiagnosticCoroutineContextException: [androidx.compose.runtime.PausableMonotonicFrameClock@d039df3, androidx.compose.ui.platform.MotionDurationScaleImpl@19c7ab0, StandaloneCoroutine{Cancelling}@1220d29, AndroidUiDispatcher@23848ae]

Here is the project gradle:
plugins {
    id("com.android.application") version "8.2.0" apply false
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "1.9.0" apply false
    id("com.google.dagger.hilt.android") version "2.48" apply false
    id("com.google.devtools.ksp") version "1.9.0-1.0.12" apply false
}

module gradle:
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
    kotlin("kapt")
    id("com.google.dagger.hilt.android")
    id("com.google.devtools.ksp")
}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.fyp"
    compileSdk = 34

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.example.fyp"
        minSdk = 26 //Change from 24
        targetSdk = 34
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary = true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose = true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.5.1"
    }
    packaging {
        resources {
            excludes += "/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.12.0")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.7.0")
    implementation("androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.8.2")
    implementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.08.00"))
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview")
    implementation("androidx.compose.material:material:1.6.4")
    implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3-android:1.2.1")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
    androidTestImplementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.08.00"))
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest")
    val nav_version = "2.7.6"
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:$nav_version")
    implementation("androidx.room:room-ktx:2.6.1") //Room
    implementation("co.yml:ycharts:2.1.0") //YChart (3rd Party)
    implementation("androidx.core:core-splashscreen:1.0.1") //Splash screen

    //Hilt Dependencies
    val daggerHiltVersion = "2.48"
    implementation("com.google.dagger:hilt-android:$daggerHiltVersion")
    ksp("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:$daggerHiltVersion")
    ksp("androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.1.0")
    implementation("androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:1.1.0")
}

kapt {
    correctErrorTypes = true
}

view model
@HiltViewModel
class EntryViewModel @Inject constructor(private val repository: DataRepository) : ViewModel() {
    private val _entries = mutableStateOf<List<Entry>>(emptyList())
    val entries: State<List<Entry>> = _entries

    init {
        loadEntryList()
    }

    private fun loadEntryList() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            _entries.value = repository.getEntryFromDate()
        }
    }

    suspend fun saveEntry(entry: Entry) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            repository.saveEntry(entry)
        }
    }
}

screen code that has crashed:
@Composable
fun AddJournalScreen(
    navController: NavController,
    entry: Entry? = null,
    viewModel: EntryViewModel = hiltViewModel(),
) {
    //Calendar Date/Time Variables
    val currentDateAndTime = Calendar.getInstance().time //Get current date and time
    val dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(currentDateAndTime) //Format date for the screen
    val timeFormat = DateFormat.getTimeInstance(DateFormat.SHORT).format(currentDateAndTime) //Format time for the screen
    val changeDateToMilis = Calendar.getInstance().timeInMillis //Convert date to Long data type for storing into database

    //Drop Down Menu
    var expandedList by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    var selectedItem by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    var textFiledSize by remember { mutableStateOf(Size.Zero) }
    val icon = if (expandedList) {
        Icons.Filled.KeyboardArrowUp
    } else {
        Icons.Filled.KeyboardArrowDown
    }

    //List of emotions from Plutchik's wheel of emotion
    val emotionList = listOf("ecstasy", "joy", "serenity", "admiration", "trust", "acceptance",
        "terror", "fear", "apprehension", "amazement", "surprise", "distraction", "grief",
        "sadness", "pensiveness", "loathing", "disgust", "boredom", "rage", "anger", "annoyance",
        "vigilance", "anticipation", "interest", "optimism", "love", "submission", "awe", "disapproval",
        "remorse", "contempt", "aggressiveness")

    //For journal input
    var journal by remember {
        mutableStateOf(
            if (entry?.journalEntry == null) {
                ""
            } else {
                entry.journalEntry
            }
        )
    }

    val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(Color.White)
    ) {
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(20.dp))
        Column(
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
            modifier = Modifier
                .height(200.dp)
                .size(500.dp)
        )
        {
            Text(text = "Date: $dateFormat", fontSize = 20.sp)
            Spacer(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .size(10.dp)
                    .height(10.dp)
            )
            Spacer(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .size(10.dp)
                    .height(10.dp)
            )
            Text(text = "Time: $timeFormat", fontSize = 20.sp, fontFamily = FontFamily.Serif)
            Spacer(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .size(10.dp)
                    .height(10.dp)
            )
            Spacer(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .size(80.dp)
                    .height(80.dp)
            )
        }
        Row(modifier = Modifier
            .width(220.dp)
            .height(100.dp)
        ) {
            Spacer(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .width(10.dp)
            )
            OutlinedTextField(
                value = selectedItem,
                onValueChange = { selectedItem = it },
                modifier = Modifier
                    .width(200.dp)
                    .onGloballyPositioned { coordinates ->
                        textFiledSize = coordinates.size.toSize()
                    },
                label = { Text(text = "Select Emotion") },
                trailingIcon = {
                    Icon(icon, "",
                        Modifier.clickable { expandedList = !expandedList })
                }

            )
            DropdownMenu(
                expanded = expandedList,
                onDismissRequest = { expandedList = false },
                modifier = Modifier
                    .width(with(LocalDensity.current) { textFiledSize.width.toDp() }),
            ) {
                emotionList.forEach { label ->
                    DropdownMenuItem(onClick = {
                        selectedItem = label
                        expandedList = false
                    }) {
                        Text(text = label)
                    }
                }
            }
            Spacer(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .width(30.dp)
            )
        }
        Row(modifier = Modifier
            .width(200.dp)
            .height(20.dp)
        ) {
            Spacer(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .width(15.dp)
            )
            Text(text = "Input your thoughts...", fontStyle = FontStyle.Italic)
        }
        Box(modifier = Modifier
            .size(400.dp)
            .padding(10.dp)
            .align(Alignment.CenterHorizontally)
        ) {
            //var inputText by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
            val maxCharLimit = 200
            TextField(
                value = journal,
                onValueChange = {
                    if (it.length <= maxCharLimit)
                        journal = it
                },
                label = { Text("What makes you feel that way?") },
                singleLine = false,
                minLines = 1,
                maxLines = 15,
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
            )
        }
        Spacer(
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(10.dp)
        )
        Row(
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceEvenly,
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        ) {
            Button(
                onClick = { navController.navigate(AppScreens.CalendarScreen.route) },
                colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(
                    contentColor = Color.White,
                    backgroundColor = Color.Red
                ),
            ) {
                Text("Cancel")
            }
            Spacer(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .width(15.dp)
            )
            Button(
                onClick = {
                    coroutineScope.launch {
                        viewModel.saveEntry(
                            Entry(
                                journalEntry = journal,
                                dateEntryInMillis = changeDateToMilis,
                                timeEntry = timeFormat.toString(),
                                emotionEntry = selectedItem
                            )
                        )
                    }

                    navController.navigate(AppScreens.CalendarScreen.route)
                },
                colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(
                    contentColor = Color.White,
                    backgroundColor = ConfirmButtonColor
                ),
            ) {
                Text("Save")
            }
        }
    }
}

Database:
@Database(
    entities = [Entry::class],
    version = 1,
    exportSchema = false
)
abstract class EntryDatabase: RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun entryDAO(): EntryDAO

}

appmodule
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object AppModule {
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideDatabase(@ApplicationContext appContext: Context): EntryDatabase {
        return Room.databaseBuilder(
            appContext,
            EntryDatabase::class.java,
            "entry_db"
        ).build()
    }
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideDao(entryDatabase: EntryDatabase) : EntryDAO {
        return entryDatabase.entryDAO()
    }
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideRepository(entryDAO: EntryDAO) : DataRepository {
        return DataRepository(entryDAO)
    }
}

database application:
@HiltAndroidApp
class DataBaseApplication: Application()

database repo:
class DataRepository @Inject constructor(private val entryDAO: EntryDAO) {
    suspend fun saveEntry(entry: Entry) {
        return entryDAO.saveEntry(entry)
    }
    suspend fun deleteEntry(entry: Entry) {
        return entryDAO.deleteEntry(entry)
    }
    suspend fun getEntryFromDate(): List<Entry> {
        return entryDAO.getEntryFromDate()
    }
}

I've done some googling and most answers seems to be gradle issues but I couldn't really see much difference beyond using different 'kapt' or 'ksp' and I'm not really sure if its a problem with the gradle or the coding problem with viewmodel/screen itself.
I was hoping to that outside of the app crashing when navigating to the screen, I can save user inputs into the database. There was a prompt for the database to install if I recall correctly so I believe the database is built.

Please don't post screenshots of code or error messages, paste it as text instead. Also does EntryDatabase_Impl really exist?

I have added code into code blocks.
I have double checked around the codes as well but I've never seen EntryDatabase_Impl before. I was following an online tutorial and they didn't specify having one as well.

Well, there must be an EntryDatabase somewhere otherwise an EntryDatabase_Impl wouldn't be expected (first line of the stack trace). Since your code doesn't show us what that is or how it is used the question isn't answerable in the current state.

Ah. I was a little confused by it. There is an EntryDatabase class but not an EntryDatabase_Impl which was what I presumed to be asked. I have added the database class on the op

Although the Room documentation is a little bit outdated, it clearly states that you need to use androidx.room:room-compiler with either ksp or kapt.
If you add this to your module level gradle's dependency block, everything should work:
ksp("androidx.room:room-compiler:2.6.1") 


Sorry. I implemented the compiler and the error now have changed to a single line when trying to run the whole app. I've added the error and the warning with the entry and dao class at the bottom.
Is this a query error or an error with the tables?

I reverted your latest change to the question because it describes another, entirely independent problem. If this answer solved your initial problem you can upvote and accept it. For anything else, please ask a new question that focuses just on that. That said, have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling (or at least, clearing the data of) the app?

Hi okay, I will do that if I can't figure out the second error. I'm not 100% sure if it does fix the problem but it feels like the the error is more localized towards the coding part so I will accept it.
I don't believe I performed any clearing of the data of the mobile app, I take it that running the emulator on the android studios sort of resets everything everytime you run the app except perhaps the database's data itself, but I haven't been able to add anything on the database.
